# Can you tether via bluetooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, tethering

I would like my iPad to connect to the internet via a bluetooth modem (in this particular case, a Samsung Omnia with a more convenient pricing plan.)

The iPad has been bought full price and thus should be carrier unlocked. However, when I go Settings → Bluetooth and tap on the device name, the only available option is "Ignore this device."

Is there a way to make this happen?

---

To be crystal clear:

```
                                   GPRS/EDGE/3G                 Bluetooth
(Internets) - - - (Mobile Carrier) - - - - - -  (Samsung Omnia) - - - - - (iPad)
```

Comment: Just to confirm, no, you can't connect to bluetooth modems with an iPad.

Comment: @jcolebrand That is not true. You can connect to Bluetooth modem as long as it supports BT PAN profile. You just can't use it as a modem only as a router.

Comment: @iskra That was what I intended it to be read as. I didn't think that you could use a BT PAN modem as a router tho. Interesting.

Comment: @jcolebrand Let's use my Nokia C2-01 as an example. From a Mac I can connect to it via BT and use it either as 3G modem (establishing connection and providing credentials  from mac) or as 3g router (via PAN and all is automatic). From iPod Touch I can only connect to it as a 3G router.

Comment: I believe you, I was just unaware.

Answer (score 7):

I read on forum that one user managed to successfully tether his Omnia to an iPad via the [WMWifiRouter,](http://global.wmwifirouter.com/consumer/) a program that turns the Omnia into a Wireless access point that the iPad can then connect to. I am nearly positive that this will not be able to be done over bluetooth, as the iOS and bluetooth are pretty restricted. Sorry I can't help with the BT issue, and I hope I have provided a decent alternative that you can work with. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

For bluetooth tethering to work you need a device that support Bluetooth PAN profile. I did my own testing and [crowdsourcing](http://ru-mac.livejournal.com/17039366.html) (it's in Russian) and it seems only Nokia S40 5th edition phones and above are relatively problem free (but not s60 ones).
SE is hit and miss and Samsung as far as my sample goes is no-no.

You probably have a better luck with some kind of Wi-Fi AP done by app from that phone if it's Android or WM one.