# My iPad's bluetooth tethering doesn't work

Tags: ipad, wifi, bluetooth, tethering

I'm trying bluetooth tethering from Samsung Galaxy Note 2. Pairing is successfully done and there are rings on iPad's status bar. However, functions using Internet connection don't work, with an error message like "cannot open ~ page because iPad isn't connected on Internet network."

Is it because iPad can't recognize Wi-Fi MAC Address? I did change my iPad's MAC address When it was jailbroken and it made my iPad's Wi-Fi to not work. Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: so Internet <-celldata-> iPad <-bluetooth-> Galaxy Note 2 ?

Comment: no, Internet -> (WiFi) -> Galaxy Note 2 -> (bluetooth) -> iPad

Comment: What is a Wi-Fi Mac Address??

Comment: It's hard to explain.. On the other words, my iPad's WiFi is greyed-out.

Comment: I'm not sure that iPads can connect to the internet over their bluetooth connection. On this related question it seems to be disputed: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5588/can-you-tether-via-bluetooth?rq=1